# How to position a select element and an icon properly with css?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have created a `select` element within a `div` with some options to change the language of the page.

The problem is, that the icon which is positioned absolute doesnt react to clicks.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-select">
   <select v-model="activeLanguage">
     <option v-for="(translation, key) in translations" :value="key">
       {{ translation.title }}
     </option>
   </select>
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.modal-select {
  position: relative;

select {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #3097D1;
}
}
```

[image]

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: I would be looking for issue not in CSS but in your component maybe. Are you getting any console.logs from click or any reaction at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean exactly.

**Here a few things that could help.**

> - Check the `z-index` css property. May be your select area is overlapping the icon.
> - If you want to click on the icon and open the `select`, you have to link it with js.
> - If you don't want any hover or animation in your icon, you can put the icon over the `select` area and give it `pointer-events: none`;
>     **For example:**

```css
.modal-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
.modal-select select {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.modal-select i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #3097D1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">

<div class="modal-select">
   <select>
    <option value="">option 1</option>
     <option value="">option 2</option>
     <option value="">option 3</option>
   </select>
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer.
The css solution worked as I wanted. (third option you provided)